# How to get all child elements excluding grandchildren

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QVhAZ/4/

How can I use `*` but only have it apply to direct children? In the example, I'd want it to only apply to the "Child" `div`s, not the "Grandchild (should not be red)" `div`s.

I don't want to apply a class to each "child" `div`, what I want is to say:

```
div#Root *:depth(1)
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you're concerned about IE6 I would use my answer. if you check @easwee answer in IE6 it will not work. Use my answer it will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
div {margin:20px;}

div#Root > div {color:red;}

div#Root > div > div {color:black;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QVhAZ/20/ 
Also using * selector selects not only divs but all elements - and it is also much slower since it has to parse all. Note that color will still be inherited by all children so you have to specify the color you want to use for all the rest.

Comment: +1 for the performance note and example for the specific problem. I'd encourage you to add more detail to your answer so archival purposes.

Comment: @Jason McCreary - I would but seems like i can't edit - some keys won't work in editor - will try later.

Comment: Yes, the `>` selector is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want direct children then use the [child selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html):

```
div > * {
  /* styles for all direct children of div */
}
```

**Note:** `color` property cascades automatically, so this becomes a bit trickier. You would have to reset the property for the *grandchildren* (see **easwee**'s answer). But to prove this indeed is the way to go, see `border` behaving correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/QVhAZ/22/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
div#Root > *
{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check out the [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) reference.

```
element1 > direct-child {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work in all browsers (most notably IE6) you should give the grand children divs ids, so you can turn off any styles given in the child for example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**STYLE**

```
.child{margin-left:10px;}
.grandchild{margin-left:0px;}
```

Bit anoying, but it does ensure it works in browsers that dont support css selectors such as `div > *`

Here is the same example that @easwee used, only tweeked so it works in IE6 http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/QVhAZ/24/